# Tab Bar Icon doesn't show?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4.5

I have a b/w PNG that is 48x60. When I set the icon image in the properties window, I just get a grey gradient rectangle instead of the image I selected.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you'd show the image you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images for tab bars and toolbars are actually alpha masks, not complete images. Only the alpha channel of the image is used.

Comment: Given the image you posted, erase all of the black so it is fully transparent, leaving just the white (though the color doesn't matter).

Comment: That was the part I didn't understand. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Tab Bar icon should be 30*30 and 60*60 for Retina Display...
Put your icone 30*30 in the Inspector tool, and name the 60*60 one with the same name adding @2x at the end of its name.
Example :
tabicon1.png (30*30)
tabicon1@2x.png (60*60)

Comment: I saw something in the documentation about having appropriate alpha. Do I need that or is that optional? I'm now getting a grey rectangle.

Comment: [Here is the Apple Guidelines][1]


  [1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html